# Mongo shell query using date

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I'm trying to run this Mongo shell query from a linux bash. The problem is that I can't check if a date in Mongo is greater than a "date" stored in a bash script variable.

This runs fine:

```
counter=$(mongo --quiet dbName --eval 'db.dbCollection.find({"updatedAt":{"$gt":ISODate("2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}).count()')
```

And the "counter" var has the expected value. But I can't use a fix value for the date. So, I created a var to store a date.

```
DATE2=$(date -d '1 minute ago' "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ");
```

This date var has the expected value. I can see that using a simple printf.

Now, the modified code, using the DATE2 instead of a fix date, won't work because the query returns "0" when it should return "1".

```
counter=$(mongo --quiet dbName --eval 'db.dbCollection.find({"updatedAt":{"$gt":"$DATE"}}).count()')
```

I've tried to modify the code above, using IsoDate() and other things, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need the put the variable in single quote inside the queries as ans below, I have tried running on my system, do let us know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the `$DATE2` inside the **single quote** as below to get the required results as below:

```
 counter=$(mongo --quiet dbName --eval 'db.dbCollection.find({"updatedAt":{"$gt":new ISODate("'$DATE'")}}).count()')
```

I have tried with `new ISODate` but will work without it also. For more help regarding the date usage click [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211173/in-bash-how-to-call-a-variable-and-wrap-quotes-around-its-value-as-part-of-a-co)